# Why does swapping the LHS and RHS of an equation give an error?

Tags: python

```
def add_10(x):
    tenplus=x+10
    return tenplus
add_30=add_10(30)
add_90=add_10(90)
```

If I swap the last two lines such that I get:

```
def add_10(x):
    tenplus=x+10
    return tenplus
add_10(30)=add_30
add_10(30)=add_90
```

There is an error. 
How does a computer read the second version?

Comment: I don't think that would work in any language. How can you make an assignment to a function call? It's not clear to me why you expect that to work

Comment: you assign by `x=value` not `value=x` and for comparing use `x==value`

Comment: I think you're thinking too much in terms of commutative examples from mathematics. In programming (in Python at least), `=` is an assignment and separate. Other languages vary in the syntax, but I don't think they vary in the ordering of the assignment.

Comment: Many programming languages use `=` for assignment even though this is mathematically confusing and/or annoying. To avoid this, e.g. Pascal uses `:=` instead; this is [being made available as a synonym in a forthcoming version of Python](/a/50071110/874188), too, although the canonical `=` assignment is not going away any time soon. (I believe `:=` was chosen as an ASCII approximation of ⇐ back in the dark ages.)

Comment: (Looking at PEP572 in more detail, you won't be able to use `:=` as a direct replacement for `=` even in 3.8.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not *equations*; they're *assignments*. Don't confuse `=` for a mathematical equality symbol. It's an assignment operator. It assigns the RHS to the LHS.

Imagine that the assignment operator were `←` instead of `=`. Then this would assign the result of `add_10(30)` to a variable named `add_30`:

```
add_30 ← add_10(30)
```

And this would... assign `add_30` to the function call `add_10(30)`? What the heck does that mean? It doesn't exactly make sense, does it?

```
add_10(30) ← add_30     # huh?
```

Indeed, I too was confused about `=` when I first started programming. We programmers are all quite used to `=` nowadays, but it wasn't necessarily the best choice back in the 70's when C was invented. In fact, Pascal—which was designed as a teaching language—deliberately invented a new, non-symmetric assignment operator so as not to confuse math students. `=` was the *equality* operator rather than *assignment*.

```pascal
add_30 := add_10(30)
if add_30 = 40 then ...
```

Too bad it didn't catch on. C won the influence wars and most modern languages base their syntax on C, so `=` for assignment it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here, "=" is an assignment operator. In the first case, you assign a known value to an unknown variable - this makes sense. In the second case, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.